# Error in Android: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

Error is indicating on setContentView() of the java file. The xml file which is going to set is given below.

I searched for this error on stackoverflow but it says that, error appear because of some image or drawable file problem. But I didn't use.
And I'm new to android so I don't understand the error.
If any other file you need then comment I will update it.

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dayplanner1/com.example.dayplanner1.Setting}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.dayplanner1.Setting.onCreate(Setting.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.dayplanner1.Setting.onCreate(Setting.java:38) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.dayplanner1:drawable/pressed" (7f080098)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f080098 a=-1 r=0x7f080098}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2441)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3737)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.dayplanner1.Setting.onCreate(Setting.java:38) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
```

This is the layout file in which error is generating.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlSetting"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    tools:context=".Setting">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/menu_settings"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sp1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#E3E3E3" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Theme"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/pressed"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="changeTheme"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvThemeTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv1"
                    android:ellipsize="middle"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Theme Color"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvThemeDes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvThemeTitle"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@id/tvThemeTitle"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/tvThemeTitle"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:ellipsize="middle"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Select background color for app"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv1"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvThemeDes"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/keyboard_arrow_right" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/sp2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/Theme"
                android:background="#E3E3E3" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Ringtone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/sp2"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/pressed"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:onClick="onRingtone"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRingtoneTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:ellipsize="middle"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Ringtone"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRingtoneDes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv3"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvRingtoneTitle"
                    android:ellipsize="middle"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
                    android:text="Select Ringtone"
                    android:textColor="#636363"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv3"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/keyboard_arrow_right" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/sp3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/Ringtone"
                android:background="#E3E3E3" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Notification"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/sp3"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/pressed"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:onClick="onNotification"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNotificationTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sw1"
                    android:ellipsize="middle"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Notification"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNotificationDes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvNotificationTitle"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvNotificationTitle"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvNotificationTitle"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:ellipsize="middle"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Show next task in notification"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/sw1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvNotificationDes"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/keyboard_arrow_right" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/sp4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/Notification"
                android:background="#E3E3E3" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Vibration"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/sp4"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/pressed"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:onClick="onVibration"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvVibrationTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sw2"
                    android:ellipsize="middle"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Vibration"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvVibrationDes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvVibrationTitle"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvVibrationTitle"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvVibrationTitle"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:ellipsize="middle"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Vibrate when remainder rings"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/sw2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvVibrationDes"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:checked="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/keyboard_arrow_right" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/sp6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/Vibration"
                android:background="#E3E3E3" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Shutdown"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/sp6"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/pressed"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="onShutdown"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvShutdownTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sw3"
                    android:ellipsize="middle"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Complete on power button"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvShutdownDes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvShutdownTitle"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvShutdownTitle"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvShutdownTitle"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:ellipsize="middle"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Reminder go off after press power button"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/sw3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvShutdownDes"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/keyboard_arrow_right" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/HighlightColor" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/White" />

</selector>
```

Comment: problem from `android:background="@drawable/pressed"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is line `android:background="@drawable/pressed"` in your code and it's 5 time repeating in your code. so you have 2 options to solve this.

1. Place **pressed.xml** in your drawable folder.
2. Remove `android:background="@drawable/pressed"` line from your xml file.

Comment: I already have pressed.xml file in drawable folder. I shown that file above. Plz checkout is there any problem with file inside?

Comment: @Dipakk Sharma I got your point but the option 1 is not working for me. Although I've file present in my drawable directory still I'm not able to use it. It is showing me the same error.